# c++ stl: пересечение множеств

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, set

подскажите, есть в stl стандартные средства или какой-то короткий оптимальный способ для решения следующей задачи:

есть 2 множества целых чисел:

```
using set_t = std::set<int>;

set_t set1 = {0,2,4,6,8,};
set_t set2 = {0,5,};
```

необходимо построить третье множество, в которое вошли бы только те элементы, которые присутствуют как в первом `set1`, так и во втором `set2` множествах.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь алгоритмом стандартной библиотеки [`set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

Заодно учтите, что есть такие операции как `set_union`, `set_difference`, `set_symmetric_difference` - могут пригодиться в будущем.